# SQL Server : cannot understand why when I create one record in table A, two records are created in table B

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am creating a record using C# in a table named units allocation. Whenever I create a record in this table I need to have fields from students table to create records in the grades table. Currently, its working but for every record I create, I get two records in the grades table.

However, the students table has only one record.

I can't seem to figure out the problem but I am suspecting it could be the sql statement. Please checkout for me.

```
private void gridControl4_EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick(object sender, NavigatorButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.ButtonType == DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonType.Remove)
    {
        GridView view = gridControl4.FocusedView as GridView;
        view.DeleteRow(view.FocusedRowHandle);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.Button.ButtonType == DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonType.Append)
    {
        gridView4.UpdateCurrentRow();
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    /*if (e.Button.ButtonType == DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonType.EndEdit)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to commit changes to the current record?", "Confirm commit",

            MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) != DialogResult.No)
        {
            gridView4.CloseEditor();
            gridView4.UpdateCurrentRow();
        }
    }*/
}

object val1;
object val2;
object val3;

private void gridView4_CellValueChanged_1(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.units_allocationTableAdapter7.Update(this.jmsDataSet22.units_allocation);

    string connetionString = null;
    connetionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;database=jms";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
        int rowHandle = e.RowHandle;
        val1 = gridView4.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView4.Columns[5]);
        val2 = gridView4.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView4.Columns[6]);
        val3 = gridView4.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView4.Columns[10]);

        string sql2 = "INSERT INTO grades (registration_no,first_name,middle_name,surname) (SELECT registration_no, first_name, middle_name, surname FROM students WHERE class_code='" + val3 + "')";

        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql2, con))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    this.gradesTableAdapter1.Fill(this.jmsDataSet24.grades);

}

private void gridView4_RowUpdated(object sender, RowObjectEventArgs e)
{

}

private void gridView4_RowDeleted_1(object sender, DevExpress.Data.RowDeletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.units_allocationTableAdapter7.Update(this.jmsDataSet22.units_allocation);
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot like homework to me. I would recommend using real names for your controls instead of gridView4. Also, your sql needs to be parameterized before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ As for the issue at hand you are going to need to debug this and step through the code. I have a feeling your CellValueChanged event is firing more than once. Possibly because of PageLoad or some other method that is causing that event to fire.

Comment: When you execute that sql statement directly in the database, are the correct number of records added?

Comment: Use a profiler trace to see what commands are being passed from the app to SQL Server.